# How to add elements to end of array in OpenCL?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

How do you add elements to the end of an array in OpenCL safely?

By safely, I mean that there are no concurrency issues, like one thread trying to add an element in the same place as another element

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will add elements from one array to another in parallel, using atomic operations for safety.

```
/*
 * list: is of size some size greater than a, one thread per element of list
 * a: is of size "size", initially 0
 * size: this is the size of array "a", initial value is 0
 * capacity: this is the number of elements allocated for "a"
 */
__kernel void AddElementsToEndOfArray(
        __global int* list, 
        __global int* a, 
        __global int size,
        __global int capacity)
{
    local int sz = atomic_add(&(size),1);
    if (sz >= capacity)
        return;

    unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);
    a[sz] = list[i];
}
```

Comment: This might work, but take into account the following: "Threads  in  the  same  warp  also  perform  memory accesses  together;  when  two  or  more  threads  simultaneously  write  to  the  same location, CUDA guarantees that one arbitrary thread will succeed."

Comment: I'm a little late, but what does that mean? I thought using atomic operations prevents concurrent access issues?